# Configure Rails 4, MongoDB, Cucumber, Capybara

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am currently in the process of setting up my first Mongodb, Rails 4 environment and need to configure the gem before running bundle install. Here is my gem file.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# User mongoid for database.
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'capybara'
  #database_cleaner is not required, but highly recommended
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

It seems Mongo wont install as I cannot find the Mongo:Config file.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is generated by running the following command:

`rails g mongoid:config`

Please read the mongoid documentation, it is quite good.